# how to download the big result in bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am new to gcp. My mission is to download the query result in patents dataset, but the result is too large. I cannot download it directly because gcp only supports download 16000 lines data.

I select several columns and the data is already too large

```
SELECT country_code, kind_code, application_kind, family_id, publication_date, filing_date, cpc.code as cpc_code, ipc.code as ipc_code
FROM
`patents-public-data.patents.publications` p
cross join unnest(p.cpc) as cpc
cross join unnest(p.ipc) as ipc
```

I expect I can download the result table, or download by the country_code in different tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complement the response of @Christopher, and for achieving your download, here the steps to perform:

- Perform your query
- Save result in (temporary) table
- Extract table to Google storage bucket
- Download file(s) where you want, manually in console or with gsutil tool

Note that there is no limitation on size, but you can have more than 1 file of the result is huge. Take care of format for nested field and prefer gzip compression for faster download!

Comment: i cannot save result in table,only can perform my query and the console show me the result ,should i save result in bigquery table ?but when i do this ,it prompt me Required parameter is missing ,because i cannot select the dataset name,

Answer (score 0):

You can [write the result](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results) in another table or [export table data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data) in Cloud Storage (take note of the export limitations)